# global C String const property in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c

Is anyway to get a global C String const property in Objective-C?

I'm doing something like this:

```
const char *content_type = [@"application/vnd.ccm.pmsg.v1+json" UTF8String];

@implementation StringChannelCallable

...

@end
```

And I get this error:

> Initializer element is not a compile-time constant

If I declare the  `content_type` inside a method, this works, but I need to have it for global purpose to don't duplicate code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use method in the variable or constant‘s declare

and you should use c language grammar to declare `const char *`, like this :

```
const char *content_type = "application/vnd.ccm.pmsg.v1+json";
```

Comment: Both the pointer and the characters it points to should be `const`, like so: `const char *const content_type = "application/vnd.ccm.pmsg.v1+json";`.